# Cloudformation: !ref a list of key/value pairs (i.e. CWM namespaces)

Tags: yaml, amazon-cloudfront

I'm getting stuck on this issue. Essentially I want to output the list of 'Namespace' key/values like below:

```
MyCloudWatchMetricStream:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::MetricStream
    Properties:
      IncludeFilters:
        - Namespace: AWS/ELB
        - Namespace: AWS/Events
        - Namespace: AWS/Logs
```

When it's declared like this:

```
MyCWMIncludeFilters:
  Type: String
  Default: 'Namespace: AWS/ELB,Namespace: AWS/Events,Namespace: AWS/Logs'
```

I've tried this to no avail:

```
MyCloudWatchMetricStream:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::MetricStream
    Properties:
      IncludeFilters: !Split [",", !Ref MyCWMIncludeFilters]
```

and getting this error on stack creation:

```
Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:<redacted> was not successfully created: 
The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyCloudWatchMetricStream].
```

Any ideas of what I can do? Alternatives? Best practices?

Thanks in advance!